# What's the determining factor in how fast data is received when performing an api request?

Tags: api, python-requests

I have two machines, both with the exact same hardware, in two different locations. One is in Texas, the other is in Oregon. The server they're contacting is in California. Both use Python and are running different scripts. These scripts perform a hundred requests at the exact same second every hour, except one is receiving the data 4 seconds ahead of the other.

What's making up the difference in those 4 seconds? Is it connection speed, the script, or something else?

Comment: Do the scripts call the same endpoints? If the scripts are not the same, and we can't see the scripts, it's hard to say what it may be down to.

Comment: Though Oregon being 400 miles approx closer to California than Texas will be a defining factor but not as much as 4 seconds.

Comment: I don't have access to one of the scripts but it should be using the same endpoint. It's using game data from one of Blizzard's api to retrieve in-game info and I think there's only one endpoint for that data.